# RecyclerView Horizontal Scroll Data changes randomly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am facing a issue in a horizontal recyclerview adapter.My adapter contains a imageview in postion 0 and remainings postion are empty.
When I do scroll from left  to right, my images reappear from position 1 to 4 and 7.If I keeps on scrolling from left to right my imageview appears in all postion here is my adapter class.I have placed this Horizontal Recyclerview Adapter in a Vertical Recyclerview Adapter.

HomeBannerAdapter.Java

public class HomeBannerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private List<HomePageList> mHomepageList;
private Context mContext;


public HomeBannerAdapter(Context context, List<HomePageList> mHomepageList) {
    this.mHomepageList = mHomepageList;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public SingleItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_single_card, viewGroup, false);
    SingleItemRowHolder mh = new SingleItemRowHolder(v);
    return mh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final SingleItemRowHolder holder, final int position) {
    final HomePageList singleItem = mHomepageList.get(position);
    holder.mTitle.setText(singleItem.getTitle());
    if (!singleItem.getBannerUrl().isEmpty()) {
        Glide.with(mContext).load(singleItem.getBannerUrl().get(0)).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).dontAnimate().into(holder.itemImage);
        Log.e("Homebanner not empty", "url" + singleItem.getBannerUrl().toString() + "position" + position);

    } else {
        Log.e("Homebanner url empty", "url" + singleItem.getBannerUrl().toString() + "position" + position);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != mHomepageList ? mHomepageList.size() : 0);
}

public class SingleItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView itemImage;
    //int position = getAdapterPosition();
    public TextView mTitle;
    public HomePageList mHomePageList;

    public SingleItemRowHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        this.itemImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);

        this.mTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        // mHomePageList = albumList.get(getPosition());
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), mTitle.getText().toString() + " position " + getPosition() + "getAdapterPosition" + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

Here is my Vertical Recyclerview Adapter

HomeDataAdapter.Java

public class HomeDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private List<FormList> formList;
private Context mContext;
private List<HomePage> homePageList;
private List<ResourceType> resourceList;
final int VIEW_TYPE_HOMEPAGE = 0;
final int VIEW_TYPE_FORMPAGE = 1;
final int VIEW_TYPE_RESOURCEPAGE = 2;

public HomeDataAdapter(Context context, List<HomePage> homePageList) {
    this.homePageList = homePageList;
    this.mContext = context;
}

public HomeDataAdapter(Context context, List<HomePage> homePageList, List<FormList> formList) {
    this.formList = formList;
    this.homePageList = homePageList;
    this.mContext = context;
}

public HomeDataAdapter(Context context, List<HomePage> homePageList, List<FormList> formList, List<ResourceType> resourceList) {
    this.resourceList = resourceList;
    this.formList = formList;
    this.homePageList = homePageList;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case VIEW_TYPE_HOMEPAGE:
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            ViewHolder homeView = new ViewHolder(v);
            return homeView;
        case VIEW_TYPE_FORMPAGE:
            View v1 = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            ViewHolder formView = new ViewHolder(v1);
            return formView;
        case VIEW_TYPE_RESOURCEPAGE:
            View v2 = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            ViewHolder resourceView = new ViewHolder(v2);
            return resourceView;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder itemRowHolder, int position) {


    if (position == VIEW_TYPE_HOMEPAGE) {
        HomePage mHomePage = homePageList.get(position);
        Log.e("albumList", "albumList" + homePageList.get(position).toString() + "position" + position);
        itemRowHolder.itemTitle.setText(mHomePage.getHeaderTitle());
        HomeBannerAdapter itemListDataAdapter = new HomeBannerAdapter(mContext, mHomePage.getResults());
        itemRowHolder.mRecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
        itemRowHolder.mRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        itemRowHolder.mRecyclerview.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(position);
        itemRowHolder.mRecyclerview.getHorizontalOffset();
        //itemRowHolder.mRecyclerview.scrollToPositionWithOffset(2, 20);
        //  itemRowHolder.mRecyclerview.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(itemRowHolder.mRecyclerview, null, recyclerAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
        itemRowHolder.mRecyclerview.setAdapter(itemListDataAdapter);
    } else if (position == VIEW_TYPE_FORMPAGE) {
        position = position - 1;
        FormList mFormPage = formList.get(position);
        itemRowHolder.itemTitle.setText(formList.get(position).getHeaderTitle());
        JobBannerAdapter itemListDataAdapter = new JobBannerAdapter(mContext, mFormPage.getResults());
        itemRowHolder.mRecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
        itemRowHolder.mRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        itemRowHolder.mRecyclerview.setAdapter(itemListDataAdapter);
    } else if (position == VIEW_TYPE_RESOURCEPAGE) {
        position = position - 2;
        ResourceType mResourceType = resourceList.get(position);
        itemRowHolder.itemTitle.setText(mResourceType.getHeaderTitle());
        ResourceBannerAdapter itemListDataAdapter = new ResourceBannerAdapter(mContext, resourceList.get(position).getResults());
        itemRowHolder.mRecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
        itemRowHolder.mRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        itemRowHolder.mRecyclerview.setAdapter(itemListDataAdapter);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int homePageListSize = 0;
    int formPageListSize = 0;
    int resourcePageListSize = 0;
    if (homePageList == null && formList == null && resourceList == null) return 0;

    if (resourceList != null)
        resourcePageListSize = resourceList.size();
    if (formList != null)
        formPageListSize = formList.size();
    if (homePageList != null)
        homePageListSize = homePageList.size();

    if (resourcePageListSize > 0 && formPageListSize > 0 && homePageListSize > 0)
        return homePageListSize + formPageListSize + resourcePageListSize;   // albumlist+formlist+resourceList

    if (formPageListSize > 0 && homePageListSize > 0)
        return homePageListSize + formPageListSize;   // albumlist+formlist
    else if (resourcePageListSize > 0 && homePageListSize == 0 && formPageListSize == 0)
        return resourcePageListSize;                         // resourceList
    else if (formPageListSize > 0 && homePageListSize == 0)
        return formPageListSize;                       // formlist
    else if (formPageListSize == 0 && homePageListSize > 0)
        return homePageListSize;                            // albumlist
    else return 0;
    //    return (null != albumList ? albumList.size()+mFormList.size() : 0);
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    int homePageListSize = 0;
    int formPageListSize = 0;
    int resourcePageListSize = 0;


    if (homePageList == null && formList == null && resourceList == null)
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    if (homePageList != null)
        homePageListSize = homePageList.size();
    if (formList != null)
        formPageListSize = formList.size();
    if (resourceList != null)
        resourcePageListSize = resourceList.size();
    if (formPageListSize > 0 && homePageListSize > 0) {
        if (position == 0) return VIEW_TYPE_HOMEPAGE;
        else if (position == formPageListSize)
            return VIEW_TYPE_FORMPAGE;
    } else if (formPageListSize == 0 && homePageListSize > 0) {
        if (position == 0) return VIEW_TYPE_HOMEPAGE;
        else return VIEW_TYPE_FORMPAGE;
    } else if (resourcePageListSize > 0 && formPageListSize > 0 && homePageListSize > 0) {
        if (position == 0) return VIEW_TYPE_HOMEPAGE;
        else if (position == 1)
            return VIEW_TYPE_FORMPAGE;
        else if (position == 2)
            return VIEW_TYPE_RESOURCEPAGE;
    }
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView itemTitle;
    public CustomRecyclerView mRecyclerview;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        this.itemTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
        this.mRecyclerview = (CustomRecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_list);

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think some of your items bannerUrls is empty. So if they're empty you do not set a default empty image with Glide or manually. Here i modified your code a little. I think this'll help.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final SingleItemRowHolder holder, final int position) {
    final HomePageList singleItem = mHomepageList.get(position);
    holder.mTitle.setText(singleItem.getTitle());
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(singleItem.getBannerUrl())) {
        Glide.with(mContext).load(singleItem.getBannerUrl().get(0)).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).dontAnimate().into(holder.itemImage);
        Log.e("Homebanner not empty", "url" + singleItem.getBannerUrl().toString() + "position" + position);

    } else {
        holder.itemImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_place_holder_for_empty_url);
    }

}
```

**Note:** Also it's a better choice to use `TextUtils.isEmpty(string)` to instead of `string.isEmpty()` to avoid `Null Pointer Exception`.

**Edit:**

Also you can let `Glide` to put placeholder to your `ImageView` by removing the `if` statement.

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(singleItem.getBannerUrl()))
```

I think this solution'll work you for too. If you choose this way **do not forget** to set an empty image to `Glide` for your empty or null urls.

Comment: Thankyou .I will try it and let you know if it's working.:)

Comment: Thanks a lot Savepopulation.Glide doesn't seem to be assigning the placeholder for empty Images.I have manually implemented the placeholder for Empty string .       holder.itemImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_place_holder_for_empty_url);